# Is there a media_upload_tabs-similar filter to add tabs to the simple/featured image picker?

Tags: javascript, media-library, backbone

There's something I have been wondering about the `media_upload_tabs` filter that lets you create new image insert sections to the add-media modal in Wordpress editor inserter. Oddly enough it seems it still does nothing at all to add anything to the simple image picker (eg. the featured image picker).

Take the Nextgen photo gallery photo picker for example - at the bottom of the left panel in add-media to a post dialog, you can see Nextgen Gallery and choose an image - but when you choose something from select a featured image for post, it shows nothing. (Which is probably why they added a *separate* button for featured nextgen-image)

Although this has been [asked before](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/Adding-the-quot-Insert-From-URL-quot-tab-to-a-3-5-upload-modal-td41003.html) I never saw an answer as to why featured image ( and any script running simple image eg. `wp.media({frame:'select'}).open()` ) cannot show a third tab?

[image: Simple picker screenshot]

Is media_upload_tabs just meant for compatibility of really old plugins doing that way of adding to insert-dialog, or are there technical reasons such as wanting a plain attachment object, not wanting html sent back, the reason there doesn't seem to be a way to add a tab to the simple picker?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. What you call "simple image picker" dialog is a "simple" `wp.media` instance. The full "media manager" dialog, with left sidebar, is a `wp.media.editor` instance. You can open them with `wp.media.open()` and `wp.media.editor.open()` respectively.

Comment: @cybmeta Exactly. What if I want to add just one more tab to a simple image media-picker - or add one more tab to the featured image picker?

Comment: `media_upload_tabs` filter, despite its name, lets you add new left sidebar sections, as you seem to know. In single media element picker there is no left sidebar at all, I really don't understand what your problem is. If I understand correctly, you want to add a tab on top of the media dialog box, not to the sections in left sidebar, in that case your question is confusing as you are not actually asking about that. Can you try to clarify?